# Is there any way to retrieve ItemID of the email messages created through EWS

Tags: email, exchangewebservices

I am trying to create an email through EWS web services.

I used CreateItem web service and could able to create the email successfully.  But I want to store InternetMessageID and ItemID of the email in a table.  I am getting CreateItem web service response as a success but could not able to get any ID's as the response.

I understand that EWS web services will send email asynchronously so that it is not giving any ID's.  Is there any way to send synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that EWS web services will send email asynchronously so that it is not giving any ID's. Is there any way to send synchronously.

No but the InternetMessageID is something that you can set when sending the email (through an extended property) so you can then use that to find the Item in the SentItems and get EWS ItemId. Storing ItemId's isn't generally a good idea because they change (unless you can use Graph ImutableId's https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-immutable-id)